# Using Match Groups with my Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
<td width="308">Services Needed: <a href="javascript:void(null);" title="weekly - 1 hour">ST</a></td>
```

I need to be able to match it, and pull info out. I am trying to use match groups with a regular expression. Belowe is my code:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"<a href=""(?<scr>[^""]*)"" title=""(?<title>[^""]*)"">(?<val>[^<]*)");
string val = match.Groups["val"].Value;
```

What I need to pull out is the "ST" value in the string. I have a match group called `val` that should be able to pull out this value. However, this regular expression does not match my string. Could someone please assist me with what is wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: why do you have "" in the string?

Comment: Im not sure exactly. I am new to regular expressions. I have one that is similar to this, and it worked for another string I am matching. I was trying to apply the same technique to this string.

Comment: The double quotes are how " characters are encoded in verbatim  string literals in C#.  `@""` defines a verbatim string literal, just as `""` defines a regular string literal.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: cheers, not a C# programmer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean it doesn't match?  I just cut & pasted your code into a new console application, and `match.Groups["val"]` contains the value `"ST"`:

```
string line = @"<td width=""308"">Services Needed: <a href=""javascript:void(null);"" title=""weekly - 1 hour"">ST</a></td>";
Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"<a href=""(?<scr>[^""]*)"" title=""(?<title>[^""]*)"">(?<val>[^<]*)");
string val = match.Groups["val"].Value;
```

Comment: Say the string has something like "\t\t\t\t\t" before it. Could this cause it to not match"

Comment: It shouldn't do, no.  It will make a difference if you've got any line breaks inside your `<a>` tag, though.  Try adding some `RegexOptions` to your match, perhaps `RegexOptions.SingleLine | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Answer (score 2):

**If** the text is guaranteed to be XML, you'll have an easier time with the XML tools than with regex.

```
string val = XDocument.Parse(input).Element("td").Element("a").Value;
```

Alternatively you could use an HTML parser. Regex would be my last choice for this. No matter how simple the HTML or XML seems, you'll always run into quirks using regex to parse it.